# Qt: How does a dock widget get its initial size?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdockwidget, qtpy

When a widget is docked, I would like it to change direction and have minimal size relative to how the dock expands.

That is,

- left/right dock => top-to-bottom direction with minimum width
- top/bottom dock => left-to-right direction with minimum height

The trouble is, whenever the direction is changed, the dock takes on a seemingly arbitrary width or height.  I cannot find a way to resize/force the dock widget to a particular size when docked.  I have tried countless variations of overriding the `sizeHint`, `minimumSizeHint`, calling `adjustSize`, and fiddling with the `sizePolicy`.

*How can I ensure the initial dock size?*

---

My basic application looks like:

[image]

The application shows primary and secondary information along with corresponding sets of controls.  A tab widget containing the primary and secondary content is set as the Central Widget.  A QStackedWidget housing the controls in respective dashboards lives in a dock.  When the tab changes, the corresponding dashboard is shown.  The code for this is given below in ***basic application code***.

The difficulty lies in that *changing the direction of the dashboard upsets the size of the dock.*

To adjust the dashboard direction, I can think of two reasonable solutions:

- via the `resizeEvent` or
- via the `dockLocationChanged` signal

### Adjusting direction via `resizeEvent`

This seems, to me, the preferable option.  It allows the user the most flexibility.  If they dislike the direction of a dock, dragging it past a particular limit will allow them to change the dock's direction.  Here I check for whether it is wider than tall.

```py
    class MyDock(QtWidgets.QDockWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(MyDock, self).__init__()

        def resizeEvent(self, event):
            size = event.size()
            is_wide = size.width() > size.height()

            container_object = self.widget().currentWidget()

            if is_wide:
                container_object.setDirection(QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.LeftToRight)
            else:
                container_object.setDirection(QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)
```

The complete code for this is given below in ***resize approach***.

### Change direction on `dockLocationChange`

As the resize event happens all the time, another approach might be to change the direction only when the dock location changes.  To do this, connect a function to the `dockLocationChanged` signal and adjust the direction depending on the dock.

```py
    class MyDock(QtWidgets.QDockWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(MyDock, self).__init__()

            self.dockLocationChanged.connect(self.dock_location_changed)

        def dock_location_changed(self, area):
            top    = QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea.TopDockWidgetArea
            bottom = QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea.BottomDockWidgetArea

            container_object = self.widget().currentWidget()

            if area in [top, bottom]:
                container_object.setDirection(QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.LeftToRight)
            else:
                container_object.setDirection(QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)
```

## Basic application code

The program consists of 5 separate classes.

For

1. `MyWindow`,
2. `PrimaryDashboard`, and
3. `SecondaryDashboard`

the reason for separation should be clear enough.

For

4. `MyDock` and
5. `DockContainer`

the separation is to facilitate overriding `sizeHint`, `setDirection`, or other methods.

```py
    import qtpy
    from qtpy import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
    import sys


    class PrimaryDashboard(QtWidgets.QWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(PrimaryDashboard, self).__init__()

            self.init_widgets()
            self.init_layout()

        def init_widgets(self):
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Primary dashboard')
            self.ok = QtWidgets.QPushButton('OK')
            self.cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cancel')

        def init_layout(self):
            self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
            self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.ok)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.cancel)
            self.setLayout(self.layout)

        def setDirection(self, direction):
            self.layout.setDirection(direction)


    class SecondaryDashboard(QtWidgets.QWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(SecondaryDashboard, self).__init__()

            self.init_widgets()
            self.init_layout()

        def init_widgets(self):
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Secondary dashboard')

            self.descr1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Thing 1')
            self.check1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()

            self.descr2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Thing 2')
            self.check2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()

        def init_layout(self):
            self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

            self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
            self.grid.addWidget(self.descr1, 0, 0)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.check1, 0, 1)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.descr2, 1, 0)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.check2, 1, 1)

            self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
            self.layout.addLayout(self.grid)
            self.setLayout(self.layout)

        def setDirection(self, direction):
            self.layout.setDirection(direction)


    class DockContainer(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(DockContainer, self).__init__()


    class MyDock(QtWidgets.QDockWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(MyDock, self).__init__()


    class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)

            self.resize(600, 400)

            self.init_widgets()
            self.init_layout()

        def init_widgets(self):

            self.tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
            self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Primary content')
            self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Secondary content')
            self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tab1, 'Primary')
            self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tab2, 'Secondary')
            self.tab_widget.currentChanged.connect(self.tab_selected)

            self.primary_dashboard = PrimaryDashboard()
            self.secondary_dashboard = SecondaryDashboard()

            self.dashboard = DockContainer()
            self.dashboard.addWidget(self.primary_dashboard)
            self.dashboard.addWidget(self.secondary_dashboard)
            self.dashboard.setCurrentWidget(self.primary_dashboard)

            self.dock = MyDock()
            self.dock.setWidget(self.dashboard)
            self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.dock)

        def init_layout(self):
            self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)

            self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.main_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
            self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        def tab_selected(self):
            tab_index = self.tab_widget.currentIndex()
            if self.tab_widget.tabText(tab_index) == 'Secondary':
                self.dashboard.setCurrentWidget(self.secondary_dashboard)
                self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dock)
            else:  # Primary
                self.dashboard.setCurrentWidget(self.primary_dashboard)
                self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.dock)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

        window = MyWindow()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## Resize approach

This code is identical to the ***basic application code*** yet with `resizeEvent` overridden in the dock widget.

```py
    import qtpy
    from qtpy import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
    import sys


    class PrimaryDashboard(QtWidgets.QWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(PrimaryDashboard, self).__init__()

            self.init_widgets()
            self.init_layout()

        def init_widgets(self):
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Primary dashboard')
            self.ok = QtWidgets.QPushButton('OK')
            self.cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cancel')

        def init_layout(self):
            self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
            self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.ok)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.cancel)
            self.setLayout(self.layout)

        def setDirection(self, direction):
            self.layout.setDirection(direction)


    class SecondaryDashboard(QtWidgets.QWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(SecondaryDashboard, self).__init__()

            self.init_widgets()
            self.init_layout()

        def init_widgets(self):
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Secondary dashboard')

            self.descr1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Thing 1')
            self.check1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()

            self.descr2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Thing 2')
            self.check2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()

        def init_layout(self):
            self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

            self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
            self.grid.addWidget(self.descr1, 0, 0)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.check1, 0, 1)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.descr2, 1, 0)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.check2, 1, 1)

            self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
            self.layout.addLayout(self.grid)
            self.setLayout(self.layout)

        def setDirection(self, direction):
            self.layout.setDirection(direction)


    class DockContainer(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(DockContainer, self).__init__()


    class MyDock(QtWidgets.QDockWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(MyDock, self).__init__()

        def resizeEvent(self, event):
            size = event.size()
            is_wide = size.width() > size.height()

            container_object = self.widget().currentWidget()

            if is_wide:
                container_object.setDirection(QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.LeftToRight)
            else:
                container_object.setDirection(QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)


    class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)

            self.resize(600, 400)

            self.init_widgets()
            self.init_layout()

        def init_widgets(self):

            self.tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
            self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Primary content')
            self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Secondary content')
            self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tab1, 'Primary')
            self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tab2, 'Secondary')
            self.tab_widget.currentChanged.connect(self.tab_selected)

            self.primary_dashboard = PrimaryDashboard()
            self.secondary_dashboard = SecondaryDashboard()

            self.dashboard = DockContainer()
            self.dashboard.addWidget(self.primary_dashboard)
            self.dashboard.addWidget(self.secondary_dashboard)
            self.dashboard.setCurrentWidget(self.primary_dashboard)

            self.dock = MyDock()
            self.dock.setWidget(self.dashboard)
            self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.dock)

        def init_layout(self):
            self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)

            self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.main_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
            self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        def tab_selected(self):
            tab_index = self.tab_widget.currentIndex()
            if self.tab_widget.tabText(tab_index) == 'Secondary':
                self.dashboard.setCurrentWidget(self.secondary_dashboard)
                self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dock)
            else:  # Primary
                self.dashboard.setCurrentWidget(self.primary_dashboard)
                self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.dock)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

        window = MyWindow()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## `dockLocationChanged` approach

This code is identical to the ***basic application code*** yet with the `dockLocationChanged` signal connected to a method which adjusts the direction based on the current dock location.

```py
    import qtpy
    from qtpy import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
    import sys


    class PrimaryDashboard(QtWidgets.QWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(PrimaryDashboard, self).__init__()

            self.init_widgets()
            self.init_layout()

        def init_widgets(self):
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Primary dashboard')
            self.ok = QtWidgets.QPushButton('OK')
            self.cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cancel')

        def init_layout(self):
            self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
            self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.ok)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.cancel)
            self.setLayout(self.layout)

        def setDirection(self, direction):
            self.layout.setDirection(direction)


    class SecondaryDashboard(QtWidgets.QWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(SecondaryDashboard, self).__init__()

            self.init_widgets()
            self.init_layout()

        def init_widgets(self):
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Secondary dashboard')

            self.descr1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Thing 1')
            self.check1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()

            self.descr2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Thing 2')
            self.check2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()

        def init_layout(self):
            self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

            self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
            self.grid.addWidget(self.descr1, 0, 0)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.check1, 0, 1)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.descr2, 1, 0)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.check2, 1, 1)

            self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
            self.layout.addLayout(self.grid)
            self.setLayout(self.layout)

        def setDirection(self, direction):
            self.layout.setDirection(direction)


    class DockContainer(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(DockContainer, self).__init__()


    class MyDock(QtWidgets.QDockWidget):

        def __init__(self):

            super(MyDock, self).__init__()

            self.dockLocationChanged.connect(self.dock_location_changed)

        def dock_location_changed(self, area):
            top    = QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea.TopDockWidgetArea
            bottom = QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea.BottomDockWidgetArea
            # left   = QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea.LeftDockWidgetArea
            # right  = QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea.RightDockWidgetArea

            container_object = self.widget().currentWidget()

            if area in [top, bottom]:
                container_object.setDirection(QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.LeftToRight)
            else:
                container_object.setDirection(QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)


    class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)

            self.resize(600, 400)

            self.init_widgets()
            self.init_layout()

        def init_widgets(self):

            self.tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
            self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Primary content')
            self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Secondary content')
            self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tab1, 'Primary')
            self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tab2, 'Secondary')
            self.tab_widget.currentChanged.connect(self.tab_selected)

            self.primary_dashboard = PrimaryDashboard()
            self.secondary_dashboard = SecondaryDashboard()

            self.dashboard = DockContainer()
            self.dashboard.addWidget(self.primary_dashboard)
            self.dashboard.addWidget(self.secondary_dashboard)
            self.dashboard.setCurrentWidget(self.primary_dashboard)

            self.dock = MyDock()
            self.dock.setWidget(self.dashboard)
            self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.dock)

        def init_layout(self):
            self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)

            self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            self.main_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
            self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        def tab_selected(self):
            tab_index = self.tab_widget.currentIndex()
            if self.tab_widget.tabText(tab_index) == 'Secondary':
                self.dashboard.setCurrentWidget(self.secondary_dashboard)
                self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dock)
            else:  # Primary
                self.dashboard.setCurrentWidget(self.primary_dashboard)
                self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.dock)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

        window = MyWindow()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of an application as a set of [Matryoshka dolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll).  An inner doll's size dictates that of the subsequent outer ones.  Clearly, an inner doll cannot be bigger than the one that contains it!   [QWidgets](https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html) are modeled similarly.

> By default, composite widgets which do not provide a size hint will
>   be sized according to the space requirements of their child widgets.

The documentation for [QWidget.sizeHint()](https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.sizeHint) goes on to say,

> The default implementation of QWidget.sizeHint() returns
>   an invalid size if there is no layout for this widget, and returns the
>   layout’s preferred size otherwise.

Altogether, **a widget's sizing comes from the inside out, based on the layout.**

If you were to implement a `resizeEvent`<sup>1</sup> for each of the objects in the *base application code*, you would see the following sequence of sizings,

1. `PrimaryDashboard` resizeEvent
2. `DockContainer` resizeEvent
3. `MyDock` resizeEvent

This is the nesting we expect.  The `PrimaryDashboard` is consulted first for its size, then the `DockContainer`, and then the `MyDock`.  Technically speaking, it's widgets all the way down.  However, the `PrimaryDashboard` contains buttons and labels which ought to be smaller than the width/height of the MainWindow in the majority of circumstances.  The first doll in the sequence to significantly affect dock sizing is the `PrimaryDashboard`.

Examining the `resizeEvent`, using `event.size()`, we can see that a reasonable minimum for a horizontal dashboard is a height of `120` pixels whereas a vertical orientation has a reasonable minimum width of `146`.  The `sizeHint()` can then be set to return the `minimumSizeHint()` and have the minimum return the `(146, 120)` for each of the dashboards<sup>2</sup>. In effect, this tells the application to prefer a minimum size of `(146, 120)` while still allowing for resizing in general.

```py
def sizeHint(self):
    return self.minimumSizeHint()

def minimumSizeHint(self):
    return QtCore.QSize(146, 120)
```

Granted, using fixed sizing can be dangerous, as absolutes are unforgiving and not flexible by definition.  However, the content likely has a natural minimum size<sup>3</sup>.  We can simply `setMinimumSize()` on the entire application to not allow resizing smaller than our `minimumSizeHint()`.

To change the direction of the dock widget content, we can use the `dockLocationChanged` signal.  We can also make the code a little neater than how it was presented in the question.  Rather than connect the signal within the dock widget, we can connect it at the instance level within `MyWindow`.  In fact, there is no need to define `MyDock` at all.  A plain `QDockWidget` will suffice.

## Docks with a minimal initial size

```py
import qtpy
from qtpy import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys


class PrimaryDashboard(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super(PrimaryDashboard, self).__init__()

        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_layout()

    def init_widgets(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Primary dashboard')
        self.ok = QtWidgets.QPushButton('OK')
        self.cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cancel')

    def init_layout(self):
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ok)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cancel)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def setDirection(self, direction):
        self.layout.setDirection(direction)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSizeHint()

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(146, 120)


class SecondaryDashboard(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super(SecondaryDashboard, self).__init__()

        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_layout()

    def init_widgets(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Secondary dashboard')

        self.descr1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Thing 1')
        self.check1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()

        self.descr2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Thing 2')
        self.check2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()

    def init_layout(self):
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.grid.addWidget(self.descr1, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.check1, 0, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.descr2, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.check2, 1, 1)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.grid)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def setDirection(self, direction):
        self.layout.setDirection(direction)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSizeHint()

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(146, 120)


class DockContainer(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super(DockContainer, self).__init__()

    def dock_location_changed(self, area):
        top    = QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea.TopDockWidgetArea
        bottom = QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea.BottomDockWidgetArea

        container_object = self.currentWidget()

        if area in [top, bottom]:
            container_object.setDirection(QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.LeftToRight)
        else:
            container_object.setDirection(QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        # Force minimumSize to ensure a sensible dashboard size
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 400))

        self.init_widgets()
        self.init_layout()

    def init_widgets(self):

        self.tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Primary content')
        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Secondary content')
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tab1, 'Primary')
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tab2, 'Secondary')
        self.tab_widget.currentChanged.connect(self.tab_selected)

        self.primary_dashboard = PrimaryDashboard()
        self.secondary_dashboard = SecondaryDashboard()

        self.dashboard = DockContainer()
        self.dashboard.addWidget(self.primary_dashboard)
        self.dashboard.addWidget(self.secondary_dashboard)
        self.dashboard.setCurrentWidget(self.primary_dashboard)

        self.dock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget()
        self.dock.setWidget(self.dashboard)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.dock)

        # Connect signal at the main application level
        self.dock.dockLocationChanged.connect(self.dashboard.dock_location_changed)

    def init_layout(self):
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

    def tab_selected(self):
        tab_index = self.tab_widget.currentIndex()
        if self.tab_widget.tabText(tab_index) == 'Secondary':
            self.dashboard.setCurrentWidget(self.secondary_dashboard)
            self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dock)
        else:  # Primary
            self.dashboard.setCurrentWidget(self.primary_dashboard)
            self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, self.dock)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

<sup>1.</sup> How one might implement such a `resizeEvent` to see who is resizing:

```py
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        print('resizeEvent for ', self, flush=True)
```

<sup>2.</sup> A natural question is, *"Why not simply set the `sizeHint()` to return the minimum size instead of calling `minimumSizeHint()`?*  The best response I have is, *"It don't work that way."*  Setting only the `sizeHint()` doesn't resize the dock to the minimum as you might expect.

The `sizeHint()` and `minimumSizeHint()` methods are virtual functions.  My guess is that Qt has other functionality, which we're not privy to, that references these methods independently, requiring us to define things this way.

<sup>3.</sup> If the content is a map, for example, it's unlikely the user would ever want the map to be `10px x 10px`.  Furthermore, it's a reasonable assumption that the user won't be working with a screen resolution less than `600 x 400` unless they're on mobile.  But if you're developing for mobile using PySide or PyQt5, there are some important questions you should be asking yourself, such as *"Why?"*.

Comment: What is the reason for inheriting from a `QStackedWidget` for the `DockContainer` class? Does this provide some benefit over using (i.e.) just a `QWidget`?

Comment: The QStackedWidget was used so that when the orientation changed, the displayed widget would change.  You're correct that for a MRE strictly about layouts, it probably isn't necessary.